# Azure Architecture for Casino type game

Tags: c#, wcf, azure, azure-storage, azure-queues

I'm creating a casino type game which allows users to bet on an event, and I plan to use Microsoft Azure as the back-end for processing and data storage (Table Storage). I'm looking for any ideas on how to validate information and notify users of any updated.

***The Idea:***
The application allows users to place bets on an event, e.g. an online bookies (PaddyPower, Ladbrokes etc).

***The Workflow:***

- The user places a bet on an event
- After the event finished the bet is settled and the user is notified
  of any winnings
- GoTo step 1

***The Scenario (simplified):***

- A user shouldn't be able to place a bet after an event has started
- A user should be notified of any problems and winnings

***The Process:***

***Solution 1*** - Using Queues:
When a bet is placed by a user, a message will be put into a Queue(used by all users) and processed by a Worker Role.

If it happens that the placed bet is too late for the event, or that the player eventually wins the bet, they need to be notified of the result.

So each active user has it's own queue which the client application polls for any updates. This will allow the client application to pick up any notifications and display them to the user.

***Solution 2*** - Using WCF & Queues:
When a bet is placed by a user, they connect to a WCF service and it will do the event start check, and they will be notified immediately of any problems.

The only way to get any notification back to the user would be to use the Queue method in Solution 1.

***Note:***

- The above scenario is simplified version of the game, but the
  mechanics are the same, so I'm just looking for good architecture
  ideas
- I'm not going to use the Notification Services because I plan
  for this application to be on both Mobile and Facebook and want to
  have the same experience across all devices
- I'm using Table Storage and not using SQL Azure
- I'm open to using the Service Bus if it makes more sense

So which of the solutions would be ideal, or is there a better solution?

Comment: How about scalability requirements? How many users, events, max bets per second, max notifications per second, size of a bet (xml?)...  This could have an impact on your design decisions.

Comment: @Herve I'm actually looking for the best approach to allow scaling based on the parameters you described. But to answer your question - I want Azure to scale up and down worker roles as needed. There's no way to really know how many users I can get, but I'm using the massive figure of 10,000 DAU. I can't see there being more than 500 bets/second. The notification queue will be polled from the client every 1-2 seconds. Also, the size of bet, will be well within the 64kb for a queue.

Comment: Two important decisions to make: one related to the client, and one related to the precision needed on the timing of the bet. If clients are phones, or mobile devices, I would encourage you to use a service (WCF) rather than exposing the queues directly to the client app. If it's a website, then the queue might be fine. However, on the second point, if you need a high level of precision for bets, such as who placed which bet when, in relation to other betters, which can affect bet pools for example, a timeout may be better than an unprocessed bet because of queue processing delays.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing something almost identical to you. After careful consideration, I have gone with the following:

SQL Azure / EF models. So much easier to work with and scalable
Service Bus Queues.
VM with Console app for the worker role. Whilst we will move to a worker or web jobs to do this, we can monitor and deploy quickly using a Console app on a VM and using the task scheduler.

When we have it right and all the possible exceptions etc are gone, we will move to either a scalable worker role, or web jobs.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you review the CQRS pattern, and in particular, the details of the reference implementation that this document covers: [CQRS Journey](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj554200.aspx).

The reference implementation uses Azure, and I think will be a good fit for your described system.  Plus, it provides an architecture that is extremely scalable and resilient.

Answer (score 0):

If I were you, I would take a good time to plan how to set PartitionKey + RowKey-combination, to support fast queries from Table Storage. Just because querying data from tables, especially without PartitionKey/RowKey, is relatively slow. I learned it in hard way :)

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit early for a new technology but maybe consider using [Orleans](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dotnet/archive/2014/04/02/available-now-preview-of-project-orleans-cloud-services-at-scale.aspx)

Oh and don't rule out using SQL Azure for your user info... especially if financials are involved. NOSQL isn't the be all and end all for persistence...

Answer (score 0):

your solution looks good, however you can think on **SignalR** for polling, which will improve the performance. the combination of 3 things should also work 
1. Web Role
2. Worker Role
3. WCF Service - Self hosted on worker role

Use of SignalR is good, because you never know, when to poll, so delegate this task to server/roles